# How to execute robot command in jenkins job on mac?

Tags: macos, jenkins, robotframework

I have installed jenkins on mac, set it up.
In Job configuration, Execute Shell , all other command works like date, pwd etc.

my scripts are in location `/Users/abcd/project/`
Under project, there are multiple folders, never mind. Scripts to be executed from `project folder`

Execute shell

```
cd /Users/abcd/project/
 robot --outputdir /Users/some_folder --variablefile variables_folder/variable.py  testsuites_folder/testsuites/test.robot
```

job fails as robot command not found. Same command works fine from terminal.
Am i missing any path settings ? missing jenkins config ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are indeed missing a path setting. Systems only look in the PATH variable to find executables. If the location of robot isn't in your PATH, there's no way for the system to find it.

Either add the location of the robot program in your PATH, or hard-code the full path to robot in the jenkins command.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like. Commands not working only from jenkins. I tried hardcoding /Library/Framweork/../lib/robot --outputdir /Users/some_folder --variablefile variables_folder/variable.py  testsuites_folder/testsuites/test.robot , error /Library/Framweork/../lib/robot is a directory

Comment: is it 'path' or 'PATH' , how do i set in jenkins job ?

Comment: @DieselKumar: the environment variable is PATH. If you hardcode the path, it needs to be to the actual robot command, not the folder. Do `which robot` from the command line to see the path that is used in the terminal.

Comment: I am new to this. But, I found something. when i execute which python on terminal,  it displays "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python". When i execute which python on jenkins, it displays "/usr/bin/python". How do i set it to Library path ?

Comment: I know its a path issue, but not aware how can i do it in mac. It'll be of great help if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (at least) to solve setting the PATH on Jenkins:

1. On the Job Configuration add a definition for the environment variable PATH
2. On the "Execute shell" or batch, instead of giving direct operating system commands, point to a shell script or batch file which includes the PATH definition.

Comment: I am struggling to add the path in jenkins. On mac terminal, which python leads to "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pytho‌​n" and the robot command works fine from terminal. When i execute through jenkins, which python leads to "/usr/bin/python" and execution fails saying as import error.

Comment: So, you could add PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH

This could be done on both options I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the python issue then I strongly advise using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), which helps in creating own virtualenv for python and then you can install the desired version of robot and simply give the path of virtualenv

Also make sure that you can able to access python and robot binaries using user 'jenkins' instead of your primary user on mac since jenkins uses user as 'jenkins'.